# How to nested paragraph in container paragraph template?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a paragraph called User Info and inside that there are two fields:

1. `field_test (Text field)`
2. `field_para_text_title (Paragraph field)`
   [image]
   Both the field values are printing when I print `{{ content }}` in `paragraph--user-info.html.twig`.

But I could not print `field_para_text_title` field alone like below:

`{{ content.field_para_text_title }}`

nothing giving for `field_para_text_title` but `{{ content.field_test }}` is working fine.

Comment: Is the nested paragraph enabled in the view mode of your paragraph type? `/admin/structure/paragraphs_type/YOUR_PARAGRAPH_TYPE/display`

Comment: @Hudri, yes it is enabled and if I print `{{ content }}` it is showing.

Comment: Hmm, I have a similar thing I just set up.  It is a paragraph with the ability to add a sidebar to it.  I used {{ content.field_sidebar }} to get the embedded paragraph.  Does your field allow for more than 1 additional paragraph?  You may need to loop thru and use content.field_para_text_title[n].  Also what does a dump of the content keys and the content.field_para_text_title give you?

Comment: I tried with content.field_para_text_title[0] but no luck. Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi, Did you get solution for this? Even, I am facing the same issue. Should we try to preprocess the field paragraph? If so, how can we get those alues inside the parent paragraph.twig

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried: `{{ content.field_field_para_text_title.0 }}` or, if that doesn't work, I would try:

- Create a template file for your paragraph field. So it would be
  paragraph--field-field_para_text_title.html.twig

  In paragraph--field-field_para_text_title.html.twig you do:
  `{{ content.field_field_para_text_title }}`